# How to align a container block to the end of a screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I have initialized a container. Inside that Container I have a child 'column' and inside that I initialized 3 icons as my widget. So, I want to align the entire container block ( White block in the picture given below) to the end of the screen vertically. As far as I know from the documentation, that it can be done by the following command-

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end

But it is not working here and showing the following output-

[image]

And here's my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: SafeArea(

          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(

              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

So, I need help to know how I can align the white block into the end of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is happening because by default the container and the column are being aligned at the top left corner of the screen. `MainAxisAlignment.end` is actually working except that your column is so short that the `.end` and `.start` are essentially the same in terms of alignments. What you need to do instead is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Align(
            widthFactor: double.infinity,
            heightFactor: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(

                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                  ],
                )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm glad! Let me know if you needed any more help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end` instead of `mainAxisAlingment`.

EDIT:
As @Stephen mentioned you need full height in order to align the children.
Besides that you can also set full width to the container to get the children exactly at the end of the screen.

Note: The top-level widget usually constrains the sub-level widgets!

```
body: SafeArea(

          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(

              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,

              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
```

If you want to keep the height to be exactly that of the icons, you can use stack instead. It will look something like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                    Icon(Icons.star, size: 50),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, the entire screen becomes white & the stars placed in right bottom of the screen. So, that's not the solution what I wanted.

Comment: @S.M.Asif use the Positioned widget that comes with the stack to give an absolute position to your stars.

Comment: Now, the entire screen becomes blue & the stars placed in right bottom of the screen. So, that's not the solution what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`

Currently you column widget is only making itself as tall as it needs to be. changing to `MainAxisSize.max` will have it expand to the full height you are looking for.

Further reading:
 https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e

Comment: Then the entire white block takes the full height. I want the white box to have the size only it needs to show the three stars  but align at the end.

Comment: Ah, in that case you do not want to stretch your column main axis with max. Your container is providing the white background, but is wrapped around the "tall" column. Instead, keep the `mainAxisSize` as `MainAxisSize.min` and wrap your Container in another Container that has `alignment: Alignment(-1,1)` You should end up with https://i.imgur.com/5qqMXqE.png - there are other ways to achieve this (such as an additional Column instead of Container) but what is best depends on where you want to take the layout from here